Why is the BPC algorithm rarely used for parallel machine scheduling problems with objective minimize makespan?
I’m currently researching parallel machine scheduling problems, specifically those aimed at minimizing the makespan ($\text{C}_{max}$). I’ve noticed that while the Branch-Price-Cut algorithm is frequently applied to vehicle routing problems (VRP), it seems to be rarely used in the context of parallel machine scheduling.
I’m curious about what aspects of the parallel machine scheduling problem make it less suitable for BPC compared to VRP?
References to literature that discuss the applicability of the BPC algorithm to parallel machine scheduling would also be useful.

Makespan objective is hard for Integer Programming approaches in general, not only Branch-and-Price. It is easy for the linear relaxation to "cheat" on this kind of objective. So, the integrality gap is usually not good, and one needs to branch a lot to prove optimality.
On the contrary, makespan is a "good" objective for constraint programming propagation. So constraint programming tends to perform much better

There are numerous uses of branch-and-price algorithms for scheduling problems with parallel machines in the literature. Here are a couple of examples:

"A stand-alone branch-and-price algorithm for identical parallel machine scheduling with conflicts" (Bianchessi et Tresoldi, 2021) DOI

"An Improved Branch-Cut-and-Price Algorithm for Parallel Machine Scheduling Problems" (Oliveira et Pessoa, 2019) DOI

"A branch-and-price algorithm for scheduling parallel machines with sequence dependent setup times" (Pereira Lopes et Valério de Carvalho, 2007) DOI

"Scheduling jobs with release dates on identical parallel machines by minimizing the total weighted completion time" (Kramer et al, 2020) DOI


One important aspect of the efficiency of branch-and-price algorithms for scheduling problems is the number of tasks scheduled on each machine. Above 20, the column generation may require too many iterations to converge in a reasonable time.
For example, the literature instances for distributed flow shop scheduling problems have hundreds of tasks to schedule on a couple of machines. That makes branch-and-price algorithms not suited to solve them.
But this is the same for routing problems. For the capacitated vehicle routing problem, branch-and-cut algorithms perform better than branch-and-price algorithms when the number of visits in each route goes above 20.
